# Customizing the tags displayed under the article title

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags, custom-action

On my joomla 3.3.1 website I would like to add the word "Tags:" before the tags that are automatically  display under the article title. 
In which file I am supposed to add this and where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place would be `/layouts/joomla/content/tags.php`. But first you need to override this layout by putting it to `/templates/your_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/tags.php`.